# Getting error with compass on mac osx yosimete

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, compass-sass, compass

I Installed ruby through terminal and version is 2.2.2 and I install compass as well on my mac now I create a folder in my www folder and through terminal I write `--compass init` i got succesffully all folder then i type compass watch in my command all done. Then I create main.scss and here I try to import

```
@import : "compass";
```

then I found this error

```
/usr/local/bin/scss --no-cache --update main.scss:main.css error main.scss  (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
Load paths:
)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

also in config.rb I got this line

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
```

and its says no file found to load

Comment: What command are you using to compile your Sass?

Comment: compass watch and a;so tried compass compile